# In iOS Charts, I want to customize each axis label instead of simply providing a string value

Tags: ios-charts

In iOS Charts, I can implement an axisFormatDelegate to provide the exact string for an axis label.

But I want to customize the label myself.  Is there a way to display custom axis labels, perhaps by providing a UIView, such as is done for header views in UITableView?

Comment: Please add some more detail so one can get context that what kind of issue you are facing ?

Comment: It appears (please correct if I'm wrong) that for axis labels, I can only set font, fontSize, color, etc and then the text to be displayed. It looks like it's displaying this in a center-aligned UILabel.                                                 I would like to be able to provide an object that does the drawing itself so I can draw anything - perhaps not even text.                   
It looks like I can do this with data plot markers - I can provide an object that conforms to iMarker (like the BalloonMaker in the ChartDemo project) and that object implements the draw method.